# Answer Query in Teradata

Tags: teradata

Query: 2. List the top 5 shoppers (number) who spent the most on Martin Luther King Jr. Day in 2000. (Hint: Use SELECT TOP 5….)

```
SELECT TOP 5 Member_Dimension.Member_Key AS "Top 5 Members", Total_Scan_Amount As "Total Scan Amount"
FROM Item_Scan_Fact, Member_Dimension, Date_Dimension
WHERE Item_Scan_Fact.Member_Key = Member_Dimension.Member_Key
  AND Item_Scan_Fact.Transaction_Date_Key = Date_Dimension.Date_Key
  AND Date_Dimension.Year_Number = 2000
  AND Date_Dimension.Day_Description LIKE 'Martin';
```

My code doesn't return any values, just an empty table. I think the source of the error is the Day_Description, but I am not sure. I believe this because when I remove the Day_Description = under the WHERE clause, the code does return a table of 5 values.

This is on teradata under the `UA_SAMSCLUB_STAR`. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is fairly meaningless, because it is not clear _which_ top 5 records you want to return.

Comment: I want to return the top 5 shoppers who spent the most. So do I put order by Member_Key or Total Scan Amount? I am really confused.

Comment: I don't know, but if you're really getting zero records back, then your query may have some other problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `Date_Dimension.Day_Description LIKE 'Martin'` condition, which returns an exact match only. Try `Date_Dimension.Day_Description LIKE 'Martin%'` instead.

And as Tim already noted add `ORDER BY Total_Scan_Amount DESC` to get the highest amounts.

Comment: @Cupcakke345: *does not work* means empty result set? You currently search for rows *starting* with 'Martin', try `LIKE '%Martin%'` to search for rows *containing* 'Martin'